# SimpleDateFormat Parsing Time and Date wrong minutes and seconds

Tags: java, android, date

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong in this code:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'").parse("2015-04-22T19:54:11.827Z"));

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'").parse("2015-04-22T19:54:11.0Z"));
```

Out put is:

```
Wed Apr 22 20:07:47 GMT+02:00 2015
Wed Apr 22 19:54:00 GMT+02:00 2015
```

Please notice the difference in minutes when there are milli seconds in the input time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), the milliseconds format value contains capital `S` characters, not lowercase `s` characters for seconds.

> s Second in minute    Number  55
>
> S Millisecond Number  978

It's interpreting `827` as seconds, and adds those seconds (847 seconds is 13 minutes, 47 seconds) to your value.

Use `SSS` for milliseconds.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
```

As an aside, you don't need to re-create your `SimpleDateFormat` more than once if it's the same.  You can create it once, save it to a variable, and call `parse` multiple times, once for each date/time string you wish to parse.

Comment: Recreating the SimpleDateFormat is just for show casing the problem, other than that your answer is just perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Use capital SSS instead of sss, as s is interpreted as seconds in SimpleDateFormat. So change your code to

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse("2015-04-22T19:54:11.827Z"));

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse("2015-04-22T19:54:11.0Z"));
```

This shall do the job for you. And in order to optimize your code use this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
System.out.println(sdf.parse("2015-04-22T19:54:11.827Z"));

System.out.println(sdf.parse("2015-04-22T19:54:11.0Z"));
```

No need to create objects again and again. Just create once and use that to parse.